# convert string (split) to list?

Tags: python

I am trying to convert a string to list and as a newbie don't know what's the easiest way to do that.

Having the list, for example:

```
strList = "[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]"
```

is there any python function that simply splits the string above?
I tried to use the method `.split()`
but it returns

```
>>> list("[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]".split())
['[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]']
```

What I would like to get is

```
result = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

so the `result[0]` would return `[1,2,3]` and 
`result[0][1]` would return `2`

Answer (score 10):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]")
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> result = _
>>> result[0]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> result[0][1]
2
```

Comment: As a side note, `ast.literal_eval` only recognize a subset of Python syntax. It has however an evil built-in twin: [eval](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval). In this case, the first is way better.

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use [json](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/json.html)

```
import json
result = json.loads('[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]')
```